# AWS BeanStalk EC2 launch script?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

When manually launching EC2 instances, we can specify a "launch script" using the [**user data**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) feature.

However, I can't seem to find a similar feature in AWS Beanstalk.

Is it not possible to do so?

(As a workaround, I know I can create a custom AMI containing the necessary launch-time script, but that means I have to create different custom AMI for each possible launch-time script configuration).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) (commands/container_commands) or [lifecycle hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) For e.g. we use the following commands to install newrelic agent

```
$ cat .ebextensions/newrelic.config
commands:
    00-cmd:
        command: yum install -y http://yum.newrelic.com/pub/newrelic/el5/x86_64/newrelic-repo-5-3.noarch.rpm
        test: "[ ! -f /etc/yum.repos.d/newrelic.repo ]"

    01-cmd:
        command: yum install -y newrelic-sysmond
        test: "[ ! -f /usr/sbin/nrsysmond ]"

    02-cmd:
        command: usermod -a -G docker newrelic
        ignoreErrors: true
```